# Problem to replace a strange string need some advise

Tags: python, pandas

I was transforming my object data to float and int and I found this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[24]'
```

from what I understand the [] are like strings and I'm having trouble removing them and leaving just the number, how do I do that? I tried to replace but when I put '[]' as a character to replace, it understands as a list, I want to remove [] to leave only the number,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `.str.strip`

```py
df['out'] = df['col'].str.strip('[]')
```

```
print(df)

    col out
0  [23]  23
1  [23]  23
2  [23]  23
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're certain that you have exactly one `[` at the start and one `]` at the end, you can just slice the string to remove the first and last character:

```
>>> foo = '[24]'
>>> int(foo[1:-1])
24
```

Another option is the `str.strip()` function, which is usually used to strip whitespace, but you can tell it to remove other characters, like brackets:

```
>>> int(foo.strip('[]'))
24
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple use eval() function. It will evaluate the expression turning string into list then use slicing to get desired result like this.

```
data = eval('[24]')
int(data[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foo = '[24]'
bar = foo[foo.find("[")+1:foo.find("]")]
print(int(bar))
```